# SQL Server - Call a REST API using a virtual CSV

Tags: sql-server, api

I have the code below that makes a request to an `API` and works fine, using `JSON` content-type to another endpoint.

```
DECLARE @Object AS int;
DECLARE @ResponSEText AS Varchar(8000);
DECLARE @Token AS Varchar(8000);
DECLARE @xmltest AS Varchar(8000);
DECLARE @hResult AS int
DECLARE @source varchar(255), @desc varchar(255) 
DECLARE @LocationId varchar(25);

DECLARE @Body AS varchar(8000) = '{
  "UserName": "test.integration12",
  "Password": "Urgent123"
}'

--EXEC sp_OACREATE 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
EXEC sp_OACREATE 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @Object OUT;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'POST', 
'https://urgentcargus.azure-api.net/api/LoginUser', 'false'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SETRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'

DECLARE @len int
SET @len = len(@body)
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SETRequestHeader', null, 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key','4f82f9d067914287979884f920d86ffb'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SETRequestHeader', null, 'Ocp-Apim-Trace:true'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SETRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Length', @len
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SETRequestBody', null, 'Body', @body
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'sEND', null, @body
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responSEText', @ResponSEText OUTPUT
```

I would like to adapt the code above in order to send the values of the parameters like a virtual `csv` file instead of an `XML` or `JSON` protocol with the appropriate format to another endpoint using a different content-type and I cannot figure it out how to do this:

```
DECLARE @Object AS int;
DECLARE @ResponSEText AS Varchar(8000);
DECLARE @Token AS Varchar(8000);
DECLARE @xmltest AS Varchar(8000);
DECLARE @hResult AS int
DECLARE @source varchar(255), @desc varchar(255) 
DECLARE @LocationId varchar(25);

DECLARE @Body AS varchar(8000) = -- here should go the parameters which are username, clientid, password and file (where file has to be the virtual CSV file with the columns and rows separated by "|"


EXEC sp_OACREATE 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @Object OUT;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'POST', 
'https://www.selfawb.ro/import_awb_integrat.php', 'false'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SETRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml'

EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SETRequestHeader', null, 'Ocp-Apim-Trace:true'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SETRequestBody', null, 'Body', @body
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'sEND', null, @body
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responSEText', @ResponSEText OUTPUT
```

I asked the owner of the `API` and they provided to me an example as shown in the print screen below:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryFfp.png)

Does anyone can give me a hint or a hand? Thanks

Comment: By "virtual" csv, do you mean replace just the JSON with comma delimited text?

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I meant. But only that is virtual, I don't use a file already generated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a virtual file, e.g. a file that you generate in memory then send as an attachment as part of the POST, then you would just need include the csv text as part of the post as an attachment with a filename. Try using PostMan to set this up using an actual csv file and analyze the POST to view how to format the csv text to be serialized over the wire as a csv file attachment.

Otherwise if you are using SQL 2016 or above, you can parse csv text using STRING_SPLIT. Hope this helps.

```
DECLARE @CsvParams NVARCHAR(256) = 
      'UserName,test.integration12,'
    + 'Password,Urgent123'

SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@CsvParams, ',');
```

The code above produces a table with the separated values:

[image]

More on STRING_SPLIT here:
[STRING_SPLIT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)